# VBA - Pasting Variant Values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem pasting a variant in Excel to a specified range. I have the following code below but the output in `[E1:E15]` is 0 for the whole range. What I would like to see is 1 all the way to 15.

I was unable to find a solution to this specific problem (partly because I could not identify what this problem is defined as withing Excel terminology). Any help for this specific code or a more natural way to complete this in VBA is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub TEST()

Dim SIZE As Integer
SIZE = 15

Dim VECTOR() As Integer
ReDim VECTOR(SIZE)

Dim i

For i = 1 To SIZE

    VECTOR(i) = i

Next i

[E1:E15].Value = VECTOR

End Sub
```

Comment: That `[E1:E15]` notation might be valid, but it's implicitly referring to the active worksheet in the active workbook. You might want to be more explicit about it and assign `ActiveSheet.Range("E1:E15").Value` instead; that way it will be much easier to later parameterize the worksheet. Not to mention that it's not a notation that's commonly encountered, so avoiding it might spare a little "WTF" moment to whoever ends up maintaining your code.

Comment: The array you created was actually a 1D array, not a Row or Column type which are 2D types which are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a horizontal array into a vertical range.

Either transpose the array or make that array 2D with the second dimension of 1:

```
Sub TEST()

Dim SIZE As Integer
SIZE = 15

Dim VECTOR() As Integer
ReDim VECTOR(1 To SIZE, 1 To 1)

Dim i

For i = 1 To SIZE

    VECTOR(i, 1) = i

Next i

[E1:E15].Value = VECTOR

End Sub
```

---

The Transpose version:

```
Sub TEST()

Dim SIZE As Integer
SIZE = 15

Dim VECTOR() As Integer
ReDim VECTOR(1 To SIZE)

Dim i

For i = 1 To SIZE

    VECTOR(i) = i

Next i

[E1:E15].Value = Application.Transpose(VECTOR)

End Sub
```

One warning: Transpose has a limitation to the number of items it can handle.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the code. I was unaware that the array created was horizontal! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

or just

```
[E1:E15] = [row(E1:E15)]
```